# Create a modal route using React.lazy() component in React Router V6

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Is it possible to create a modal route with lazy component pages? By that I mean the `<Modal/>` is rendered inside the `<User/>` page instead of being a page of its own.

A modal route is working perfectly with elements:

```
<Routes>          
  <Route path="user" element={<User/>}>
    <Route path="modal" element={<Modal/>} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

But when I use lazy components, the `<Modal/>` is not rendered inside `<User/>`. At `/user/modal`, the `<User/>` content is gone and the `<Modal/>` is rendered as a new page:

```
const User = lazy(() => System.import("./page/User"));
const Modal = lazy(() => System.import("./page/Modal"));
<Routes>          
  <Route path="user">
    <User/>
    <Route path="modal">
       <Modal/>
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

I have the `<Outlet/>` inside the User Page as per the [preview article](https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v6-pre/):

```
function User = ()=>{
   return (
     <div><Link to="modal">modal</Link><Outlet/></div>

   )
}
```